# What does the phrase "glory days of videogame links" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "glory days of videogame links" in the following sentence from the description of the game Pixel Pro Golf:

> With easy controls and retro graphics, Pixel Pro Golf brings you back
> to the **glory days of videogame links**.

I know that Links is a famous golf series. If the said phrase refers tot the series, the word links should start with a capital letter.

Do you think the phrase "videogame links" can refer to something else here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Links* game series is named after the noun [**links**:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/links#English)

> A golf course, especially one situated on dunes by the sea.

So "the glory days of **videogame links**" refers to the heyday of virtual (video game) golf courses in general, not just the one specific game series.